# Multipart/form-data request to AWS Elastic Beanstalk returns status 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, multipartform-data

I have an API in my web application that makes it possible for users to upload files (audio and images), and everything works perfectly fine when I use an npm module like multer or multiparty for the parsing of the files. However, when I run this application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, any multipart/form-data request to the server fails.

(Note: I am using Node.js for my backend and API)

What is the best way to go about sending files to my upload api on AWS EB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was something wrong with the environment my backend was running on; Making a new environment and running it there worked!